# Extracting modal informations in Abaqus with python

Tags: python

I've tried to do a script in Python but this doesn't work.

The error is about the line `fichier = open('results.txt','w')`, but I don't understand where the mistake is. Do you have an idea about the solution to this problem?

My **code** is :

```
from odbAccess import *
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import types
import visualization
from math import *
from odbMaterial import *
from odbSection import *

frame_k=[]
odb=openOdb(path='demoplaque.odb','r')   # opens database with specified name

for k in range (len(odb.steps['modal'].frames)):
    frame_k.append(odb.steps['modal'].frames[k]

fichier = open('results.txt','w')
i=0
for data in frame_k:
        if str(data) != '[]':
                fichier.write(str(data))
                i=i+1
fichier.write('\n')
fichier.close()
```

Comment: Abaqus told me that the syntax is invalid for the line fichier =open('results.txt','w')

Answer (score 0):

in line:

```
for k in range (len(odb.steps['modal'].frames)):
    frame_k.append(odb.steps['modal'].frames[k]
```

You need to close bracket:

```
        frame_k.append(odb.steps['modal'].frames[k])
```